# Can I batch edit Xcode search scopes?

Tags: xcode

Xcode has this feature that allows to create **search scopes** to determine the files that will be considered when Cmd+F something.
I have created a bunch of scopes for different scenarios (eg. only interfaces, only implementation files, only files within a particular feature, only tests, etc).
But now I would like to make some changes and don't want to click around on each scope.

Is there any way to manually edit this as a text file or similar?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it is possible.

> The search scopes are stored in a file named IDEFindNavigatorScopes.plist . This file can be found either in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/ or in the xcuserdata of your workspace, such as FindNavigator.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/

https://patrickbalestra.com/blog/2020/02/09/xcode-find-navigator.html